# Typescript error in plotly.js/index.d.ts during npm run build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, plotly

I am trying to use

```
import createPlotlyComponent from 'react-plotly.js/factory';
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(window.Plotly);
```

[image]
in the js file within my existing react project which is written in typescript.

I encountered typescript issue on npm run build. ',' expected
Has anybody encountered this before?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the typescript version to 4.1.2 fixed it for me :)